# Issue with trying to use some on-the-fly-generated code with Python

Tags: python, import, pycharm, reload

While running my code ("Test_Use_Generated_Code.py"), I do generate on-the-fly a new python function within a separate python file ("gen_code.py") using intermeaditae function ("write_gen_code.py") that I want to use while still being in the same run.
My issue is that the generated code is not seen.
My guess is that as the interpreter did not see the code at the beginning of the run (because not yet created) and so does not see the new generated code.

I am using Python 3.7 & Pycharm (64 bits).
Can you help me soving this issue (if possible!)?

I have tried different things such as Import_reload(module) but I still cannot use the generated code.

#### Origin Function:

```
   import time, sys, os
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
   from write_gen_code import write_gen_code
   from gen_code import *
   class test_code():
       def __init__(self):
            Code_FileName = str("gen_code.py")
            open (Code_FileName, "w").close ()
            write_gen_code ("gen_code.py")
            #Expect some code here to load newly generated code
            MyObject = getattr (created_code, "Dummy_function") (self)
       exit()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication (sys.argv)
        uiMain = test_code()
        sys.exit (app.exec_ ())
```

### Write Function:

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
    class write_gen_code():
        def __init__(self, filename):
            with open (str (filename), "w") as file:
            content ="# ' Code      : -*- coding:utf-8 -*-"
            content = content + "\nimport sys"
            content = content + "\n\nclass created_code():"
            content = content + "\n\tdef Dummy_function(self):"
            content = content + "\n\t\tprint(\"hey hey\")"
            content = content + "\n\t\tpass\n"
            file.write (content)
        file.close ()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication (sys.argv)
    uiMain = write_gen_code("gen_code.py")
    sys.exit (app.exec_ ())
```

### Generated Code:

```
    import sys
    class created_code():
        def Dummy_function(self):
            print("hey hey")
            pass
```

I do expect:
hey hey

but so far I get:
  File "C:/Test_Use_Generated_Code.py", line 11, in **init**
    MyObject = getattr (created_code, "Dummy_function") (self)
NameError: name 'created_code' is not defined

Comment: why are you writing code in file from Python in the first place?

Comment: You call a class that hasn't yet been created in the work environment because your 
 generated code is not "generated" yet

Comment: 1_ I do have to generate some code with associated functions or names that are dépendent on an external generic file (so with unknown names)

Comment: 2_when calling my function with getattr (*) my code has already been generated with the precedent write function. so it does exists, but the class is not "callable"